# Capturing logcat on LG Android 6

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat, lg

I need to record the log on LG phone running Android 6. The recording should happen in the background for a few hours while the phone is not plugged to USB. What I used to do in other phones was simply pipe the logcat to a file on the device:

```
logcat -v threadtime > /sdcard/logs.txt &
```

But when I do this on an LG phone I recently got, it does not output anything to that file. I have tried the following commands:

```
logcat -v threadtime > /sdcard/logs.txt &
logcat -v threadtime > /mnt/sdcard/logs.txt &
logcat -v threadtime | tee /sdcard/logs.txt &
logcat -v threadtime | tee /mnt/sdcard/logs.txt &
```

They all resulted empty files. I also installed aLogrec app from the Store. The app shows it's recording the logs, but the file it creates is empty.

I also tried using `-f` option in adb, but here is what I got:

```
shell@g4stylusn:/mnt/sdcard $ logcat -f /sdcard/logs.txt
couldn't open output file
1|shell@g4stylusn:/mnt/sdcard $
```

No description as to why it could not open the file. I checked and it's not permission issues.

Any idea why I might not be able to record the logs, and what options I have?

Thanks

Comment: I have also having same issue .. empty logs getting after some time.

Answer (score 3):

Could be an LG bug. Try

```
adb shell -x logcat
```